# how to instant so that the script cannot be decoded evalhook

Tags: php

how to make something that I make is easy but can not be executed by evalhook

```
if(extension_loaded('evalhook')){
exit;
}
echo "helow world";
```

as a result it can still be solved evalhook so how is it not easy to solve evalhook